# Custom RPCs not decorated

Tags: polkadot-js, rpc

I added some custom RPC endpoints to a substrate blockchain, but when I connect to the node with a simple script it prints:

```
API/INIT: RPC methods not decorated: ...
```

The RPCs work, but don't show up in the polkadot Apps.

How can I decorate my custom RPC endpoints and will they show up in the polkadot Apps afterwards?

Comment: i am sure there is a command to run but you can add the the custom rpc types in spec/typeBundle.js in polkadot Apps directory

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only information that is exposed to APIs are the names of the RPCs, this excludes -

- the actual description of the method (optional, but useful in some case)
- the actual input parameters and their types
- the actual return type

So in this case the API is correct - it can *see* that there is a methods, but if has no idea how to "decorate" it since it has no information about the input and output parameters. (This is unlike anything exposed by the runtime, e.g. state/extrinsics/errors since with metadata v14 we have all the pertinent information on these, including the types)

You would need to manually fully describe the methods and add it to the [API initialization options](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/rpc.custom)

For the apps UI specifically, this is specified in the [apps-config package](https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/tree/master/packages/apps-config/src/api/spec) on a per-chain/runtime basis.

Comment: hi jaco i have a question about RPC, i created a new issue for it here: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/6169/how-to-decorate-rpc-correctly