# How to call a contract using a custom RPC?

Tags: polkadot-js, smart-contract, api, custom-rpc

I uploaded a smart contract to the Aleph Zero test net.

When I tried to query one of the methods of said smart contract, I encountered this error:

```
2022-08-09 09:34:28        API/INIT: RPC methods not decorated: alephNode_emergencyFinalize
2022-08-09 09:34:28        API/INIT: aleph-node/30: Not decorating unknown runtime apis: 0x2be3f75b696ad1f6/1
```

[This post](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2210/custom-rpcs-not-decorated) answers, what the problem is, however I have problems implementing the solution.

```
const provider = new WsProvider('wss://ws.test.azero.dev');

const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider,
    rpc: {
        firstModule: {
            myMethod: {
                description: 'Returns AccountId',
                params: [],
                type: 'AccountId'
            }
      }
} });

const address = 'contract address'
const account = 'account address'

const contract = new ContractPromise(api, abi, address)

const gasLimit = 3000n * 1000000n;
const storageDepositLimit = null

const { gasRequired, storageDeposit, result, output } = await contract.query.myMethod(
    account,
    {
      gasLimit,
      storageDepositLimit,
    }
);
```

The code above results in the same error.
The polkadot{.js} documentation suggests to call the custom RPC like this:

```
const { gasRequired, storageDeposit, result, output } = await api.rpc.firstModule.myMethod(
    account,
    {
      gasLimit,
      storageDepositLimit,
    }
);
```

However, this results in this error:

> TypeError: api.rpc.firstModule.myMethod is not a function

How can I call the method from my smart contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this problem was completely on me.

I censored the contract address, so it is impossible to know, but
I put in the hash for the contract and not the actual address.

Changing 'address' to the actual contract address and putting a 'gasLimit'
of 5000000000000 made the declaration of a custom RPC unnecessary and
I was able to call the methods.